# How to remove a particular part of the file name?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have files like

```
#md0.xvg#
#md0.xvg# 
#md0.05.xvg#
#md0.05.edr#
#md0.1.edr#
#md0.1.xvg#
:    :
:    :

#md1.xvg#
#md.edr#
```

I want to rename them without # .

```
md1.xvg
md1.agr
```

I wanted to write a program in C or shell But, I have no idea how to start with. If somebody can help , I will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following bash script or command

```
$ rename 's/\#//g' * -v
```

> **rename**: Command
>
> **'s/\#//g'**: Replace expression
>
> *****: All files
>
> **-v**: Verbose

**Expressions detail:**

```
   s    /  /#          /            / g
   ^       ^^              ^^^^^^     ^
Replace  # character with nothing   all
```

If you want to do a dry run (not actual renaming), use the following command:

```
$ rename 's/\#//g' * -vn
```

It would just tell the existing and new (renamed) name of files and won;t do the actual renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` (exemple with zsh)

```
% tr -d '#' <<EOF
heredoc> #md0.xvg#
heredoc> #md0.xvg# 
heredoc> #md0.05.xvg#
heredoc> #md0.05.edr#
heredoc> #md0.1.edr#
heredoc> #md0.1.xvg#
heredoc> :    :
heredoc> :    :
heredoc> #md1.xvg#
heredoc> #md.edr#
heredoc> EOF
```

Result will be

```
md0.xvg
md0.xvg 
md0.05.xvg
md0.05.edr
md0.1.edr
md0.1.xvg
:    :
:    :
md1.xvg
md.edr
```

Some other options without *heredoc*, assuming the file with your data is called `yourfile.txt`

```
% tr -d '#' < yourfile.txt
% cat yourfile.txt | tr -d '#'
```

Use the `>` redirection to send the output to another file

```
% tr -d '#' < yourfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer. What's this heredoc > , It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The *heredoc* thing is just a way to get data to `tr`. You can use your file with, eg, `tr -d '#' < yourfile.txt` or `cat yourfile.txt | tr -d '#'`. After that, you can send the output to another file with the `>` redirection `tr -d '#' < yourfile.txt > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways. In `C`, one of the easiest ways will be using the array indexing to remove the `#`s. Sample algorithm

- Prerequisite: File names are in format `#......#`
- Target : Get the filename without the starting and ending `#`s.
- Algorithm:

  1. Read the file name into an array, say `source_buffer`.
  2. calculate the `strlen()`, store into `len` (or whatever).
  3. create a destination buffer (say, `dest_buffer`) which will hold the modified file name.
  4. use `memcpy(dest_buffer, &source_buffer[1], len-2);`
  5. null-terminate `dest_buffer`.

Alternatively, for a more complex and sophisticated naming pattern , you can look into string manipulation functions prototyped in `string.h` header, like [`strchr()`/`strrchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash` to rename files like

```
for i in ${files[@]}; do
    new_name=$(tr -d '#' $i)
    mv $i $new_name
done
```

Alternatively, this C code will strip first and last char from filename supplied as command line argument

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char * oldname = argv[1];
    char * newname = strdup(argv[1]);
    newname++;
    newname[strlen(newname) - 1] = 0;

    if (rename(oldname, newname))
        printf("Error: unable to rename the file");
    else
        printf("File renamed successfully");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash, You can use:

```
for i in ${files[@]}; do
    mv $i ${i//#/}
done
```

with c, You can use strtok() function to remove '#' then mv.

```
strcpy(temp, path);    
token = strtok(path, "#");
system("mv temp token");
```